# Why do I need to use && instead of || in the following if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I thought I had to do this:

```
if (building.floorplan || selectedCategory !== 'outdoor') {
  // run code
}
```

(Run the code if the building has a floorplan OR if the selected category is not outdoor.)

But it turns out, the code only works with `&&`:

```
if (building.floorplan && selectedCategory !== 'outdoor') {
  // run code
}
```

(Run the code if the building has a floorplan AND if the selected category is not outdoor.)

Shouldn't the first case also run the code? Since the condition meet if there's  a floorplan OR the selected category is not outdoor?

Comment: The first should work. What is the type of ".floorplan" ?

Comment: The first statement will run if either of the conditions evaluate to true. The second statement will run if both of the conditions evaluate to true. Yes, this means the first will always work if the second works.

Comment: Those are two fundamentally different expressions. So without any further context it's impossible to say why you needed to use one over the other. But yes, the OR case will run when the AND case runs, but is a lot looser so it'll also run in cases when the AND case won't run.

Comment: @Chris It's a `String`.

Comment: When I am not sure about operators priority, I alwasy use parentheses to enforce the priority I want. I do it almost always, since it gives more readable code

Comment: You'll need to provide more context for logic. But I suggest building a truth table and some unit tests to double check expectations.

Comment: What is the value of said string when you are expecting a false value?

Comment: What Chris seems to be hinting at is that your first condition might not be working the way you expect it to.  Check this article then look at your value for 'floorplan' when it is supposed to be false: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Run the code if the building has a floorplan OR if the selected
>   category is not outdoor.

If you use an OR `||` operator, then you are saying that if first one is true, then no need to look forward.

So,

```
if (building.floorplan || selectedCategory !== 'outdoor') {
  // run code
}
```

will not look beyond first condition if `building.floorplan` is not falsey.

On the other hand, if you use AND `&&`, then you are saying that if first one is false, then no need to look forward

So,

```
if (building.floorplan && selectedCategory !== 'outdoor') {
  // run code
}
```

will not look beyond first condition if `building.floorplan` is not truthy.

> Shouldn't the first case also run the code? Since the condition meet
>   if there's a floorplan OR the selected category is not outdoor?

First case is checking if there is a `floorplan`, then no need to look to next condition. So, **No** - first condition will not work as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this to be related to the `type` that `.floorplan` is. As mentioned in your comments beneath the question, `floorplan` is a string.

The fact that it couldn't be understood from the code alone suggests that some more expressive code should be the order of the day. A future dev would find it difficult to come along, and at a glance, understand what a false value represents - is it `""` or `"no floorplan"` or `"ain't no body got a floorplan"`, etc.

I would suggest something like:

```
if(build.floorplan !== "" || selectCategory !== "outdoor") {...}
```

The true comparison will depend on the context of your particular application.

Alternatively, add a method to your build object, something like `hasFloor` that does the checking, so your method can be rewritten as:

```
if(build.hasFloorplan() || selectCategory !== "outdoor") {...}
```

Personally, unless it's a bool type, I will explicitly check in my conditionals, especially in a language like JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to assume these two variables are not equal to outdoor do the following:

```
if ((building.floorplan == selectedCategory) && (selectedCategory != 'outdoor')){ 
    //code goes here
}
```